# What is the use of CSS display "list-item" if there is no display "list"?

Tags: html, css, list, responsive-design

I'm looking to create a HTML list element with list items from div tags. I know there is `display:list-item`, but if I have this:

```
 <ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
 </ul>
```

to get this:

```css
.item { display: list-item};
.list { display: block };
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
</div>
```

doesn't get me anywhere.

**Question:**
Is there a way to get the `<ul>` equivalent using `<div>` tags and why is there a `display:list-item` when `display:list` does not exist?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML list elements - such as `<ol>`, `<ul>`, `<dl>` - are [block-level elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements) like `<div>` which is a generic block-level container.

The only difference is that UAs apply some `padding`, `margin` on that elements within the user-agent stylesheet. For instance Google Chrome applies the following to `<ul>` elements:

```css
ul, menu, dir {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: disc;
  -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
  -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
  -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
  -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
}
```

As can be seen, there is `padding` at the right side of the `<ul>` which allows the markers (bullets) to be displayed beside each item (at the left). Otherwise they would stick out of the box and can not be seen.

Therefore, to fake the effect of `<ul>`, you'll end up with something like this:

```css
.list {
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
```

Alternatively, we could change the position of markers to `inside` of the box by giving `list-style-position: inside` to the list items.

Answer (score 2):

With `list-item` you are doing this:

> The element generates a block box for the content and a separate list-item inline box

So you need to define the list-item, this property allows you to define another properties like this:

```
.list > div {
    display:list-item;
    list-style-type: disc;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Check this [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bftf6xk9/)

*Note* >>

If you want to define some kind of bullet type image I suggest the method of  the answer of @Doctus but if you want some numeric let's go with this one and change `asterisks` by `decimal`

Answer (score 2):

What you have will work fine. All you need to do is add a `list-style` property to the `.list` item.

E.g.

```css
.item {
    display: list-item;
    list-style: disc inside;
}
```

Comment: This creates a bulleted list but it does not created the *equivalent of `<ul>`* as requested. So I wonder what was really the question.

Comment: @frequent Actually it doesn't need to use `list-style` property necessarily. You could see the bullet just by adding some padding to the right side of `.list`. To fake the effect of `<ul>` (taken from Chrome): `.list { margin-top: 1em; margin-bottom: 1em; padding-left: 40px; }`.

Comment: @HashemQolami please post your note as an asnwer ... since is the real answer, the only thing that helps of celmar answer and mine is  the `inside` rule

Comment: @HashemQolami: agree with Danko

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't even bother with the `display: list-item`, create a container, nest the div "items" in it, then use the pseudo elements to create the bullets:

http://jsfiddle.net/0j5uch7q/

```css
.list
{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.item
{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.item:before
{
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    width: 6px;
    height: 6px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    background: #000;
    position: absolute;
    left: -13px;
    top: 6px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
</ul>

<hr>

<div class="list">
  <div class="item">A</div>
  <div class="item">B</div>
  <div class="item">C</div>
</div>
```

You may want to play around with positioning, but that's the basics of it.

Comment: This does not answer either of the questions asked.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela "Is there a way to get the <ul> equivalent using <div> tags"

Comment: @frequent Yeah I'd suggest you use one of those :)